# RequestDelegate as discard parameter in custom middleware class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I saw the following code:

```
class ReaderMiddleware
{
    IReader reader;
 
    public ReaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate _, IReader reader) => this.reader = reader;
     
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Current Value: {reader.ReadValue()}");
    }
}
```

`_` assumes not used in code argument. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/discards):

> ... isn't assigned a value, and may not even be assigned a storage location.

Why the author of the post uses it in class if `RequestDelegate` is a mandatory parameter? Does it mean that no other middleware is used after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a middleware component is responsible for calling the next item in the pipeline. See this [example in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-webapplication):

[image]

However, in the code you show, this is an example of *terminal middleware* because it does not process any more in the chain. This is why the author has discarded the `RequestDelegate` parameter. Another option would be to completely elide that parameter entirely:

```
public ReaderMiddleware(IReader reader) => this.reader = reader;
```

If you wanted to extend the middleware to call the next in the chain, you would do something like this:

```
class ReaderMiddleware
{
    RequestDelegate next;
    IReader reader;

    public ReaderMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IReader reader)
    {
        this.next = next
        this.reader = reader;
    }
     
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Current Value: {reader.ReadValue()}");

        // Call the next middleware in the pipeline
        await next();
    }
}
```

Comment: _Another option would be to completely elide that parameter entirely:_ Doesn't that go against convention?

Comment: @DenisMicheal No, there is no convention here other than the naming of the `InvokeAsync` method and the parameters is takes. Unless you implement `IMiddleware` in which case the `next` parameter is passed in the `InvokeAsync` method and not in the constructor.